# Conditionally colspan a row in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, gridview, html-table

I've got a GridView, that is working fine, but now I want to make some tweeks for some information.
My doubt is that, I've got some cells (5), which the first is fill, but the rest are empty, and so, I wanted to post a message along the 5 cells.
How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlistmov" runat="server" CellPadding="0" CssClass="middletable" CellSpacing="0">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <td><p>Nº.</p></td>
                    <td><p>Position</p></td>
                    <td><p>Ref</p></td>
                    <td><p>2 Ref</p></td>
                    <td><p>Name</p></td>
                    <td><p>Qty</p></td>
                    <td><p>Date</p></td>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("n") %>' ID="lblmarca" nome="ref" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pn") %>' ID="Label2" nome="volume" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ref") %>' ID="lblrefcb" nome="ref" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductNumber") %>' ID="Label1" nome="ref" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName1") %>' ID="Label7" nome="ref" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliveredQuantity") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliveryDate") %>' /></td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>


using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                using (DataSet data = new DataSet())
                {

                    myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                    if ((myDataAdapter.Fill(data) > 0))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            DataRow Row = data.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                        }
                        dtlistmov.DataSource = data;
                        dtlistmov.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dtlistmov.DataSource = "";
                        dtlistmov.DataBind();
                    }
                }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: sorry but not understand ***I wanted to post a message along the 5 cells. How can I do that?***

Comment: On the empty cells, post a message like "No information avaiable"

Comment: is it a gridview or a datalist?because that markup is for a datalist.